# We are in the post-vb tag era, can we zonk it for good?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

The Great Tag Cleanup of 2012 got us rid of [vb](/questions/tagged/vb). It got remade again on July 12, and manually removed today.

It's bound to come back. Can it be banned?

Comment: Thanks, @animuson. Where were my manners?

Comment: Maybe synonymize it? [tag:vba] or [tag:vb6] or [tag:vb.net]? My point is, it will be used again, like so many other tags are misused.

Answer (score 1):

Synonymized with [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), since that is now the most common usage.